# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(params)')

Tags: react-native

I am working on react-native applying the application provider tag from ui-kitten and I receive in error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(params)'). Below is where the code is throwing the error. Any help on this would be appreciated.

[React Native code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZmBE.jpg)

[Error thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnboG.jpg)

Comment: would you mind adding code and errors as text to your post

Comment: Yes, will add it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing any props to the `ApplicationProvider`. Try the code provided in the getting started [guide](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/guides/getting-started#manual-installation).

```
import * as eva from '@eva-design/eva';
import { ApplicationProvider } from '@ui-kitten/components';
...
export default () => (
  <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light}>
  ...
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the direction and code, it worked. Yea, I have to use  `{...eva}` and `theme={eva.light}` to make it work. I thought I could leave that out.